# rails : undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, controller

I'm a beginner in rails and I need to compare 2 DateTime on my controller :

```
@b = Book.find(params[:book][:id])
if @b.expiry_date > DateTime.now
  ... something here ...
end
```

But I get this error :

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

Anyone have an idea why ?

Comment: It means that particular book object's `expiry_date` is `nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operators are methods in ruby, so your `undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass` error indicates that `@b.expiry_date` is nil on this line: `if @b.expiry_date > DateTime.now`.

You can use a short-circuiting logic to only evaluate the condition if `@b.expiry_date` is present.

```
if @b.expiry_date && (@b.expiry_date > DateTime.now)
```

The if expressions is only true if both sides of the `&&` are also true, so`(@b.expiry_date > DateTime.now)` won't be executed if the first condition, `@b.expiry_date`, is false or nil.

Otherwise, you'll need to add logic/validations to ensure the existence of `expiry_date`.

Comment: To be exact, the `expiry_date` of `@b` is nil, not `@b`.

Comment: You're right, I got ahead of myself as I was writing.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check that the record isn't nil in your if statement as shown:

```
    @b = Book.find(params[:book][:id])
      if !@b.expiry_date.nil? && @b.expiry_date > DateTime.now
      ... something here ...
    end
```

If all Books are supposed to have expiry dates you should add a validation that insists an expiry date is included when creating/updating a Book record in your Book Model!